# Mapper issue in AutoMapper 10.1.1 version

Tags: automapper

Seeing the below error from the AutoMapper flow after upgrading from 8.0 to 10.1.1 AutoMapper

Usage:

```
   var response = new RAccountDetailResponse
        {
            retailerAccount = _mapper.Map<RAccountDetail>(retailer)
        };
```

Error

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'PRM.Web.Core.Interfaces.Models.IRAccountDetailModel' cannot be used for parameter of type 'PRM.Web.Api.Contracts.RAccountDetail' (Parameter 'arg1')
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Invoke(Expression expression, Expression arg0, Expression arg1, Expression arg2)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Invoke(Expression expression, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Invoke(Expression expression, Expression[] arguments)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.GenerateTypeMapExpression(MapRequest mapRequest, TypeMap typeMap)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.BuildExecutionPlan(MapRequest mapRequest)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.CompileExecutionPlan(MapRequest mapRequest)
   at AutoMapper.Internal.LockingConcurrentDictionary`2.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<.ctor>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at AutoMapper.Internal.LockingConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.GetExecutionPlan(MapRequest mapRequest)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.GetExecutionPlan[TSource,TDestination](MapRequest mapRequest)
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.MapCore[TSource,TDestination](TSource source, TDestination destination, ResolutionContext context, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, IMemberMap memberMap)
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source, TDestination destination)
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TDestination](Object source)
```

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: there are many other section of the code where I use AutoMapper and it seems to be erroring only in this spot

Comment: tried with latest from MyGte still the same

Comment: I don't see how that's possible :) A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Answer (score 0):

Configure AutoMapper to know what types you want to map

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMap<retailer, RAccountDetail>();
});
```

Validate your mappings (remove it before release)

```
configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Create the mapper

```
var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
```

Execute the mappings:

```
var retailerAccount = mapper.Map<retailer, RAccountDetail>(retailModel);
```

**Example**

```
// Map BankModel(source) to Bank (destination) 
public void CreateBank(BankModel bankModel)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<BankModel, Bank>());
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    var bank = mapper.Map<BankModel, Bank>(bankModel);
    service.CreateBank(bank);
}

// Map Bank (source) to BankModel (destination)
public BankModel ReadBank(int ID)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Bank, BankModel>());
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    var bank = service.ReadBank(ID);
    return mapper.Map<Bank, BankModel>(bank);
}
```

Comment: @lhdina this is a working piece of code in AutoMapper 9.0; its failing only after the ugprade of the package, so doubt if building via configuration would make any difference

Comment: @Gans, its work for AutoMapper Version 10.1.1

Comment: are you saying that the direct invocation is deprecated in 10.1?
_mapper.Map<RAccountDetail>(retailer)

Comment: @Gans, I'm using AutoMapper 10.1.1 from https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/  with the code sample above and it works fine.